# PHPLaravel: How do I display a View

Tags: php, laravel, view

I'm trying to display a View having the following codes:

```
{!! Stored in /resources/views/about.blade.php !!}
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title')
Conway's Game Of Life - About
@endsection

@section('content')
<h2>Conway's Game Of Life - About</h2>

<p>The Game of Life, also known simply as Life, is a cellular automaton devised by the British mathematician John Horton Conway in 1970.</p>
@endsection
```

Then the following main blade page:
`<!-- Stored in /resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->
    <title>@yield('title')</title>

    @yield('content')`

After this a routes.php comes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('/about/', function () {
     return view('about');
});

Route::get('/about/', 'HomeController@About');
```

I get the following errors:

`InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:

View [index.blade] not found.
ErrorException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:

View [index.blade] not found. (View: C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\apache2\htdocs\GameOfLife\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
ErrorException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:

View [index.blade] not found. (View: C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\apache2\htdocs\GameOfLife\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php) (View: C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\apache2\htdocs\GameOfLife\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)`

What shall I do better to avoid having errors?

Thanks for helping me out of trouble!

**PS, Suggestion:**
Neither of the answers below find a solution to the problem. Can this be that I use PHP7, not any lesser version? It might influence the execution of Laravel program codes.

Answer (score 1):

You have view called about.blade.php but you are missing view called index.blade.php which is expected since you defined that route

```
   Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

Also since you are using layout templates, on top of all your views you must specify which view are you extending with @extend

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-a-layout

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all make sure that under `layouts` folder `app.blade.php` exists and it has these two statements `@yield('content')` inside body and `@yield('title')` between `head` tags.
Do one of these not both

```
Route::get('about', function () {
     return view('about');
});
OR
Route::get('about', 'HomeController@About');
```

And make sure that your `index.blade.php` exists under `views`

If you still get error please comment.